# Fourier transform of an even function

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}, \mid x \mid<\frac{1}{2} \\
0, \mid x \mid\geq \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
$

1. Find Fourier transform
2. Find the Fourier transform of the convolution
   $*_{i=1}^{n}f(x)=f(x)*f(x)*\cdots*f(x)$

The function is even as

if $x=\frac{1}{3}$ we get $f(-x)=f(-\frac{1}{3}))=\frac{1}{2}=f(\frac{1}{3})=f(x)$

if $x=5$ we get $f(x-)=f(-5)=0==f(5)=f(x)$

So we have to evaluate $$\hat{f(x)}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\cos(\omega x)dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\cos(\omega x)dx$$

If $\omega=0$ we have:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}dx=\frac{1}{4 \pi}$$

If $\omega\neq 0$ we have:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\cos(\omega x)dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left.\frac{\sin(\omega x)}{\omega}\right|_0^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\sin(\frac{\omega}{2})}{{2\pi}\omega}$$

We just take 
$$2\pi \hat{f}(x)^n= \frac{2\pi}{(4 \pi)^n}$$
for $\omega=0$

and

$$2\pi \hat{f}(x)^n=\frac{\sin^n(\frac{\omega}{2})}{\omega^n}$$

For $\omega\neq 0$

Is it correct? we change the limit of integration from $\infty$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ because it is zero whenever $|x|\geq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, it is correct to limit the integration to $|x| < \frac12$. And your calculations look correct.

Comment: @md2perpe I think I made a mistake it should be $\frac{2\pi}{(4\pi)^n}$ and not $(\frac{2\pi}{4 \pi})^n$

Comment: And I had edited your text according to your error. I have fixed the text.